# How do I add material Icons to an array and pass it through props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, google-material-icons, material-icons

I am working on a project with react, typescript and material icons

I want to add my material icons to an array and pass it through props

but it shows me the letters(string) of the icon

example is in this code which it displays on the browser is

```
export interface IDashboard {
  dashboardItems: {
    color: string;
    count: number;
    itemName: string;
    icon?: any;
    backgroundColor: string;
  }[];
}
```

Dashboard

```
import { IDashboard as IState } from "../utils/Types";
const Dashboard = () => {
      const dashboardItems: IState['dashboardItems'] = [
        {
          color: "white",
          count: 5,
          itemName: "Users",
          icon: "<GroupIcon />",
          backgroundColor: "#373793",
        },
      ];
 return (
       <DashboardItems dashboardItems={ dashboardItems } />

 )
}
```

DashboardItems

```
import { IDashboard as IProps} from "../utils/Types";
import GroupIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Group";
const DashboardItems: React.FC<IProps> = ({ dashboardItems }) => {
  return (
     <div>{dashboardItem.icon}</div>
)}
```

How do I make it show Icon instead of letters(string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `IDashboard` change the type of icon to `JSX.Element`
and in the `dashboardItems` just remove the apostrophe from you component  `icon: <GroupIcon />,` .

Comment: I am getting this error TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.

Comment: My bad, the type should be `JSX.Element`